# a differential equation equation related to fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, power-series

I am really struggling with this one. Any help is welcome!

For equation $f''(z) + p(z) f'(z) + q(z) f(z) = 0$, where $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are fixed polynomials.
Given $f(0)=f_0$, $f'(0)=f_1$, prove that there exists a solution $f(z)$ given by the sum of a power series, whose radius of convergence is infinite.
More generally:
What if, $p$ and $q$ are fixed holomorphic functions on the whole complex plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an implication of Fuch's Theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs's_theorem

In general, if $p_0,\ldots,p_{n-1},q$ are holomorphic functions is a open disk $D$ (resp. $\mathbb C$, resp. a simply connected domain $\Omega$) and $z_0\in D$ (resp. $z_0\in\mathbb C$, resp. $z_0\in\Omega$), then then initial value problem
\begin{align}
x^{(n)}+p_{n-1}(z)x^{(n-1)}+\cdots+p_1(z)x^{(1)}+p_0(z)x=q(z), \\
x(z_0)=\zeta_1,\,x'(z_0)=\zeta_2,\ldots,x^{(n-1)}(z_0)=\zeta_n,
\end{align}
has a unique solution, for every $\zeta_1,\ldots,\zeta_n\in\mathbb C$, which is holomorphic in $D$ (resp. $\mathbb C$, resp. $\Omega$).

In your particular case, try to solve the problem assuming that $p(z)=p_0+p_1z+\cdots+p_kz^k$, $q(z)=q_0+q_1z+\cdots+q_\ell z^\ell$ and $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nz^n$, and plug all the power series (finite and infinite) in the ODE to obtain a recursive relation for the $f_n$'s. This in turn will allow you to show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|f_n|^{1/n}=0$, which implies that $f$ is entire.

Comment: thx!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Picard-Lindelöf resp. the Picard iteration formula to show analytical solvability over any finite interval, conclude for the whole real line, and then, if necessary, compare coefficients.